# Retrieving a data from Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'd like to get a String which is in an `Object` in Parse without the `something.put("blalala")...`.

Only by taking the string from Parse. What's wrong with my code ? How can I do that ?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


TextView textView;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Parse.initialize(this, "blablablbalba", "blablablabla");

    final ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");

     //txtv
     textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     //txtv


     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");

     query.getInBackground("theid", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
         @Override
         public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
             if (e == null){

                 String playerName = gameScore.getString("playerName");
                 textView.setText(playerName);

             }
             else {
                 textView.setText("Mince !!!");
             }
         }
     });







 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should read `String playerName = parseObject.getString("playerName");`  parseObject is the variable that's holding the result from the query, not the gameScore variable

(EDIT:)Straight from the docs:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not possible, I did the exact same thing as in the documentation.

Comment: No you did not - see my edit above - do you see the line in the if-statement that says "//object will be your game score"?  the variable object is what's holding your object from your query, not the variable gameScore.  Please read the docs carefully and try to understand what you're doing, don't just copy and paste then ask stackoverflow when it doesn't work

Comment: @Galaxy please mark as correct, since my answer is absolutely correct

Comment: You're right I don't really understand. I'll try to, and figure out by myself thank you.